# angular 2 setTranslation in ngx-translate 7.0.x

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate method setTranslate to merge the new_lang.json file into my lang.json file at runtime with some condition. I am passing 3rd Parameter of method as true (shouldMerge).

new_lang.json file has the same json object keys as lang.json has, but with some value changes. when my condition gets true, new_lang.json gets deep merged into lang.json and forms an updated lang.json.

Sample code -

in my app.component.ts inside ngOnInit -

```
translateObject.use('lang'');

if(condition == true ) {

translateObject.use('new_lang').subscribe( (response: any) => {
translateObject.seTranslate('lang', response, true);
}) ;
```

Current behavior

After merge when i am trying to get the json data using key (translate.get() ) method, it is picking up the new values from new_lang.json instead of updated lang.json file.

Expected/desired behavior
Values should be taken from lang.json instead new_lang.json

Please tell us about your environment:

**ngx-translate version: 7.0.x

**Angular version: 2.x.x

**Browser: all

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the methods with correct parameters? Because both `translateObject.use()` and `translateObject.setTranslation()` methods accept a language code as their first parameter, not a file name.

Comment: Sorry, typo in sample code. I am passing the lang /json file name only without dot json extension. Please suggest.